# cpufreq_stats.c error on kernel compilation

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Whenever I try to compile a kernel, I get this error: http://pastebin.com/fKE3M47v

How do I get around this? I can't find a patch online that works. I've tried changing the configuration with config and menuconfig, but the changes have no effect. I'm building on Ubuntu Mate 15.10 with Linux kernel 4.2.0, if that matters.

This is the kernel I am building: http://github.com/FireLord1/android_kernel_samsung_logan2g/tree/cm-13-testing

Comment: This is not an official repo, but is maintained by a single person. Your better ask the author about your problem. BTW, current content of file `drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_stats.c` doesn't fit into the error message (it has only 428 lines while error refers to line 475). You may try to update and see whether situation changes.

Comment: Thanks for replying :) the maintainer doesn't know, that's why I posted it here. Also, I think you are looking at the wrong branch. The cm-13-testing branch (which is the one I'm using has 775 lines.

Comment: Yes, `cm-13-testing` branch fit into error message. Googling for undefined function *of_find_node_by_path* has found 2 references (in other subsystem): the [first one](http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/linux-arm-kernel/2013-October/202996.html) suggests that configuration option `CONFIG_OF` should be enabled for use the function, the [second one](https://lists.linaro.org/pipermail/lsk-commits/2015-August/000185.html) suggest that the function should have empty definition even in case when the option is disabled. In any case, filling bugreport is better than posting it here.

Comment: @Tsyvarev What I meant is that he doesn't know the fix to it. The kernel is 3.0.101. There is no bus/KConfig folder in the kernel, and when I apply the second patch, it doesn't do anything. same errors.

Comment: `What I meant is that he doesn't know the fix to it.` - I understand that, but Stack Overflow is not a *debugging service*. We may point to the error in a small program ([mcve]), we may help with problem in the well-known project, even it is large. But your case fit into neither of them. You (or the mainteiner) should try to debug by youself or search other resources.

Comment: As for references, they are about other subsystems. Of cource, directly following them doesn't help in you problem. As I said, check that configuration option *CONFIG_OF* is enabled for your kernel. If it is not, and there is no way to enable it, then try to define missed function with empty body, and see whether it will work.